# How to do an mySQL query that return unique values from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, django-admin

Hi I have a big database consists of 100+ tables. I have 3 tables named auth_group(id and group_name), auth_permission(id and permission_name) and auth_group_permission(Associative table b/w these two tables) consists of fields id, group_id and permission_id. There are many groups inside the auth_group table and each auth_group may have many permissions too. Some groups may have same permissions as other groups. I needed to create an excel sheet which `contains Group and permission, if same permissions are coming for different groups include in both the group rows`. I needed to create a query that returns `A list of groups and their corresponding permissions grouped together`. Like example:

```
Managers : can create record
            can delete record
            etc.
 Engineer : create data
             delete data
```

I have tried the following query, but didn't worked out as subjected.

`select distinct G.name, P.name from auth_group G, auth_permission P, auth_group_permission GP where G.id = GP.group_id AND P.id = GP.permission_id LIKE G.name LIKE 'BIG_RA_%'`

Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "100+ tables" This kind of problem is sometime symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
SELECT G.name,
   GROUP_CONCAT(P.name)
 FROM  auth_group_permission GP
 INNER JOIN auth_group G ON G.id = GP.group_id
 INNER JOIN auth_permission P ON P.id = GP.permission_id
 WHERE G.name LIKE 'BIG_RA_%'
 GROUP BY G.name
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried `SELECT G.name,GROUP_CONCAT(P.name)
FROM  auth_group G
INNER JOIN  auth_permission P ON P.id = GP.permission_id
INNER JOIN auth_group_permissions GP ON G.id = GP.group_id
WHERE G.name LIKE 'BIG_RA_%'
GROUP BY G.name` but returned an error as `Error in query: Unknown column 'GP.permission_id' in 'on clause'`